# C# & XAML Popup doesn't show in screenshot

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, c#-4.0, popup

I have many popups in a custom GUI application.  These popups are window objects, not popup objects.  The popups do not show up in a screenshot when using the Print Screen button on the keyboard.  Instead, the disabled mainwindow below is all that shows in the screenshot.  The popup never flickers or disappears, it just doesn't show in the screenshot.

```
WindowInstance.IsEnabled = true;
WindowInstance.Refresh();
DisplayPopUpWindow(WindowInstance);
```

The code in DisplayPopupWindow:

```
private void DisplayPopUpWindow(Window theWindow)
{
    if (theWindow != null)
    {
        if (theWindow is MessagePopup)
        {
            // Only show one popup at a time (queue is handled elsewhere)
            RemovePopUpsCommand.Execute(true, null);
        }

        ActiveWindow.IsEnabled = false;  // main screen disabled

        foreach (KeyValuePair<Window, int> aPopup in popUpWindows)
        {
            if ((aPopup.Key.IsVisible) && (aPopup.Key.Opacity == 1) && (aPopup.Key != theWindow))
            {
                // if window is a lower priority then disable it
                if (aPopup.Value > displayPriority)
                    aPopup.Key.IsEnabled = false;
            }
        }
        theWindow.Show();
        theWindow.Opacity = 1;
    }
}
```

Is there some property in the XAML that affects whether the window is visible for screenshots?  This is a large issue as this also affects some remoting software we use in that popups do not display on the shared screen.  Also affects our combobox implementation.

The "popups" are actually their own standalone windows.  Some have instances created once during application startup and simply shown/hidden when needed, however, most are created on demand to be displayed.  This problem affects both types.

The remoting software used is axeda access remote.

Comment: is this happened on WindowsXP?

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287373/take-screenshot-of-wpf-popup-window.  An alternative might be Alt + Print Screen.

Comment: The software is run on Windows XP embedded, but I have the screenshot issue while developing in Windows 7.  I have a program that allows me to take the screen capture, but the bigger problem here is the remoting software.  I can change the GUI program itself, but I cannot change the remoting software.  I figured the screenshot issue would have the same root cause and could lead to a solution.

Comment: I had similar problem with XP before (popup not showing in remote desktop), and I believe you need to set `AllowsTransparency="False"` for your `Window`, you can have a try.

Comment: I believe we want transparency on the windows, they have rounded edges, but I'll check on that...

Comment: FYI: [Problem with the AllowTransparency and Popup controls in WPF](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/369500/problem-with-the-allowtransparency-and-popup-controls-in-wpf)

Comment: I believe I would have to modify more than just adding the one property to test this.  I should have mentioned that the popups in question are actually window objects, not popup objects.  We have not had any issue with them not showing in front on the XP system itself, only on the remoting software.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly I had the same problem and I think it was related to setting the popup windows parent to the main window that fixed it, I'd have to look at my code at home to confirm.

So make sure this is correctly set.

EDIT:

Try using this code when you create the Window object:

```
MainWindowVariable.Owner = Window.GetWindow(this)
```

You can read more here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tried setting the parent using
`[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern int FindWindow(String ClassName, String WindowName);
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndParent);
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();`
and
`IntPtr popupPtr = new IntPtr(FindWindow(null, theWindow.Name));
IntPtr parentPtr = GetForegroundWindow();
SetParent(popupPtr, parentPtr);`
This gets null

Comment: Sorry that is so jumbled, not sure how to get my newlines to stick for the post (I used shift-return to get them in there)

Comment: I wasn't getting the pointers to my windows correctly, but I fixed that.  I still show the parent as 'null' after passing the correct pointers for the parent and child windows into SetParent.

Comment: How are you spawning the new window?  What remoting software are you using?  Are you using Prism in the WPF app?  Update the question with more details.

Comment: The windows are all created in App.xaml.cs.  So "this" could not be used as the owner.  I instead used App.Current.MainWindow, which set the owner.  I confirmed it still had the owner when displayed, however this did not fix the issue.  App.Current.MainWindow.Owner is null, should that not be the case?